# How to know which network is connected?

Tags: wireless, networking, ethernet

How can I see using command-line whether I am connected to network using eth0, eth1 or wln0 etc?

Well, to elaborate, I have a desktop sidebar which I installed using program "conky". This sidebar has meter that shows internet speed. Since I am not using eth0, I need to make a minor change in ~/.conkyrc file. I need to replace "eth0" with whatever network is being used by my wireless card to connect to internet (via a router).

Comment: `ifconfig` may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may very well be connected to multiple networks at once, depending on your setup.

If you are interested in knowing which interface is being used for Internet traffic, try using the `ip route` command and look at the default route.  For example, on my system it shows that traffic will travel over `eth0` if it isn't matched by any of the other rules in the table:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.10  metric 1
```

Comment: Eureka! It was "eth2". I found it using ifconfig, since I knew my manually configured ip address, it was used by eth2. However, ip route is a better option, since it clearly showed "eth2" to be the one and only network being used.